# Bulk Api 2.0 max 2 retries instead of 10

Tags: bulk-api, bulk, pricebookentry, bulk-api-v2

I recently started huge PricebookEntry bulk update, around 40 mln records in one of sandboxes where locks are unavoidable.
I am relying on the documentation that 10 retries are guaranteed per batch:

[image]

However from hands on experience it's not working for me that way:
[image]

As you can see there are max 2 retries for the given batch which afterwards is marked as completed, however I can still see failed records and once queried failed Results they remain untouched by the bulk update so they failed to be updated.

My question is:
Why batch was only retried 2 times and marked as complete even though it has failed records.
I am expecting up to 10 retries from Bulk API to make sure all records from the batch are updated.
Batch is not marked as failed even though there are lot's of failed records.
It's confusing to look at a completed job with failing records, bulk api 2.0 should provide up to 10 retries for given batch

The errors on the batch say Timeout it took longer, however once queried failing records the error is unable to lock row

Does that mean that I have to reprocess manually all the failing records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10 is not the *minimum* guaranteed retries, but rather the *maximum* guaranteed. In other words, after 10 retries, the job will definitely fail. If a record fails because of a transient error, for example, because of a failure to acquire a row lock, the retries can continue up to the maximum. If the record fails for permanent errors, such as invalid data, there's no need to try 10 times, and the process will abort early. In addition, if the transaction exceeds 10 minutes, it will be terminated without further retries. It appears in your logs that it took longer than the allotted time of 10 minutes. You'll need to rerun the failed records, as they were not updated successfully. If you plan your records with some care, it may be possible to rearrange them to minimize row lock times.

Edit: Here's my hastily done illustration of how to break up the data using a striping technique. The X axis are the Price Book Ids, the Y axis are the Product Ids, and where they intersect are the Price Book Entries you're trying to create/update. This assumes that you have a full matrix of data. If there gaps or other oddities, you may need an alternative approach, though I hope this will get you started on your project.

[image: Striping load order across a large matrix of price books and products]

Comment: So if I understand correctly it's limited to 10 retries within 10 minutes processing time for the batch OR 10 minutes processing time for the batch. And in this case it exceeded 10 minutes so the batch is terminated, but I think the status should not be completed right? It should be failed instead.
It's almost impossible to avoid locks with given dataset even after ordering them by Pricebook and Product, it looks like I will have to try Bulk v1 to reduce the batch size to not exceed 10 minutes per batch.

Comment: @Bithermal (a) the documentation suggests you only get a failed status if 10 retries in less than 10 minutes. I'd log a documentation bug and see if they can clarify. (b) A naive pricebook/product ordering won't work in either API. That's where your contention comes from. Instead, you'll need some kind of striping algorithm, where each batch is a combination of products and books not related to the nearby batches. e.g. Batch 1 has books 1-100 and products 1-100, 2 has 101-200, 101-200, etc. Much later: books 1-100, products 101-200, etc.

Comment: @Bithermal At least, if you're in parallel mode. In Bulk 1 serial mode, you'll get no contention at all, but it will be orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: Been there :) 94 hours in serial mode.
Those locks on pricebookentries are very challenging, I was using power BI and python to perform data transformation based on the bulk query results, I did a striping algorithm to group pricebook lookups for each batch 200 records to exclude collision, however I think I still received locks from product lookups, but I gave up there and just sorted by Pricebook and Product, it should probably deserve a separate thread, but is there any tool you can suggest to perform this striping that you suggested, I am new in such large data transformations

Comment: @Bithermal I'll see about writing some code for it, but for now, imagine a table with one axis a product id, the other a price book id, and each cell in the table is the price book entry. Imagine 100 rows and columns is one batch. Start with (0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), etc until you walked the entire diagonal. Next, offset by one so you get (0, 1), (1, 2), etc until you complete that diagonal. Wrap around as necessary. The last batch should be at (m - 1, n), where m is the number of rows and n is the number of columns.